# Whenever I run a chrome extension, it returns the error: File "chrome-extension://jgfhlfelemcfpljpmokkhemkabpknbjc/js/chrome_ex_oauth.html" not found

Tags: oauth, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a simple extension to display the users email address using OAuth. When I do this, the above error is returned.
My manifest.json is here: http://pastebin.com/8V0vYBcz

Comment: can you send the "manifest.json"

Comment: Can you share the background.html also?

Answer (score 0):

I Think the error is clear, check the folder "JS" in your extension files you will not find file with name "chrome_ex_oauth.html” , maybe you typed the wrong path in the manifest.json like below

```
"app": {
"launch": {
  "local_path": "js/chrome_ex_oauth.html"
}
```

Or maybe you added a wrong script path

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS/chrome_ex_oauth.js"></script>
```

may be the write one is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauth.js"></script>
```

Comment: There is no js folder in the extension. I had it at one time, but I fixed all the links to it. My backgroung.html script is as follows:
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauthsimple.js"></script>
  
<script type="text/javascript" src="chrome_ex_oauth.js"></script>

Comment: maybe it's a browser cache, remove all browser cache and try again,